# Join with exclusion of previous match

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Let's say i have a table "Players that scored in the match" with the following structure, where player 1 scored twice in the match (appears twice) and player 5 scored once:

```
playerId | odd
1        | 15
2        | 30
1        | 15
```

And that i have an array of players ids i have selected, that i bet will score in that match.

***Use case 1***

Players ids selected: [1, 5]
Here, i bet that player 1 and 5 will score once in the match (ids appears once in the array). Since player id 1 actually scored twice in the match, my bet remains partially correct, so my score is 15.

***Use case 2***

Players ids selected: [1, 1, 5]
Here, i bet that player id 1 will score twice (appears twice in my selected ids), and id 5 will score once.
Since player id 1 scored twice in the match, my score is 15 + 15.

***Use case 3***

Players ids selected: [1, 1, 5] and let's imagine player 1 scored once in the match.
My bet is partially correct. I get +15.

***Use case 4***

Players ids selected: [3].
I bet plyaer id 3 score, it's not the case, i get 0pts.

Here is a code example where i two use cases, the first one is Working ok with Mikhail's solution, **but not the second one**:

```
DECLARE matchs STRING;
DECLARE bets STRING;

SET matchs = "[{'playerId': 550, 'odd': 15, 'scored_at': 1}, {'playerId': 550, 'odd': 15, 'scored_at': 2}]";
/* Use case 1 --  working */
/*SET playerIdSelected = "[550, 9]";*/

/* Use case 2 --  NOK */
SET playerIdSelected = "[550, 9, 550]";

SELECT
  SUM(CAST(first_odd AS INT64)) total
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(scorers, '$.odd') ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(scorers, '$.scored_at') LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] first_odd,
  FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(matchs, '$.')) AS scorers
  WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(scorers, '$.playerId') IN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(playerIdSelected))
  GROUP BY JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(scorers, '$.playerId')
)
```

Comment: then, it is still not clear what that second case that does not work. can you please present sample input and expected output in clear text so we can help you better

Comment: You are right. I re-writed my post and my use cases with expected outputs, let me know if it's still not clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(first_odd) total
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(odd ORDER BY scored_at LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] first_odd
  FROM `project.dataset.scores`
  WHERE playerId IN UNNEST([1, 5, 3])
  GROUP BY playerId
)
```

As you can see - i am using `scored_at` column to identify the first score for each player. Your data should have such field that identifying order of events  - usually this is a timestamp or something similar

If to apply to sample data from your question with added `scored_at` field - output is

```
Row total    
1   15
```

> Below is answer for updated question - initial question was explicitly asked for "exclusion of previous match" thus the logic in above first answer was to follow this. Now below logic reflects logic explained in presented use cases

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.scores` as (
  select 1 playerId, 15 odd, 1 scored_at union all
  select 2, 30, 2 union all
  select 1, 15, 3   
), selection as (
  select [1, 5, 1] playerIds
)
select ifnull(sum(odd), 0) total
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by playerId order by scored_at) as score_pos
  from `project.dataset.scores`
) join (
  select playerId, count(1) max_scores
  from selection s, s.playerIds as playerId
  group by playerId
) using(playerId)
where score_pos <= max_scores
```

Comment: Mikhail, thank you so much for your response and sorry for my delay. I've had an accident that kept me away from development for 2 weeks, but i'm back on my feet now and i'm going back at it !
I'm trying your piece of code, i will let you know asap :)

Comment: After trying, i think your solution is working for one use case, but not the second one where i have selected twice the id 1, and i should get  (15 + 15)  = 30. I'll edit and post a dummy code example

Comment: This will definitely works for me. It is also really a smart way of doing it. I just have to make it fit in my initial request, but the base is perfect. THANK YOU Mikhail !